# Star as interesting via transcript says about pinning too

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars, chat-transcript

If you'll star message in chat transcipt as interesting via drop down menu by selecting an item "*star as interesting*" in the result you'll see the following:

> You have starred and pinned this message.

> [image]

But I don't have an ability to pin a message, I'm not a room owner (anymore).

Comment: @ShadowWizard in my case the message has never pinned by someone.

Comment: oh never mind, reproduced. Still, original should be edited, still a dupe.